# Android Flipboard App animation

Tags: flipboard

I'm Implementing Flipboard Animation in my activity pageIndicatorActivity its showing an error i.e The method Page(NoteViewAdapter) in the type FlipViewController is not applicable for the arguments 
     (PageIndicatorActivity.NoteViewAdapter)

this is the error I'm facing

here is my code

```
package com.horizontalscrollviewwithpageindicator;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.aphidmobile.flip.FlipViewController;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PageIndicatorActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

         ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
            notes.add("Come");
            notes.add("On");
            notes.add("Flip");
            notes.add("Me");

            //You can also use FlipViewController.VERTICAL
            FlipViewController flipView = new FlipViewController(this, FlipViewController.HORIZONTAL);

            //We're creating a NoteViewAdapter instance, by passing in the current context and the
            //values to display after each flip
            flipView.Page(new NoteViewAdapter(this, notes));

            setContentView(flipView);

    }

    public abstract class NoteViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;        
        private ArrayList<String> notes;

        public NoteViewAdapter(Context currentContext, ArrayList<String> allNotes) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(currentContext);        
            notes = allNotes;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return notes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View layout = convertView;

            if (convertView == null) {
                layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
            }            

            //Get's value from our ArrayList by the position
            String note = notes.get(position);

            TextView tView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.note);

            tView.setText(note);
            return layout;
        }
    }
    private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.antartica1, R.drawable.antartica2,
            R.drawable.antartica3, R.drawable.antartica4,
            R.drawable.antartica5, R.drawable.antartica6,
            R.drawable.antartica7, R.drawable.antartica8 };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This library works for fragment or activity that shows list of items using adapter and animation works between each item. So for flipview simply set Note view adapter



      flipView.setAdapter(new NoteViewAdapter(this, notes));